# Store output of for loops in Dataframe R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, rbind

I am trying to store the results of two for loops in a dataframe.

```
    comp <- c(mp, ct, n158, out)
    df <- data.frame()
    for (i in length(comp)){
      lst <- comp[i]
      d <- data.frame()
      for (t in seq(1, sapply(lst, length))){
        ob <- sapply(lst, function(m) m[t] ) 
        dt <- train_data[(train_data$ADDR_POSTALCODE == as.numeric(ob)),]
        dt$AREA <- names(lst)
        d <- rbind(d, dt)
      }
      df <- rbind(df, d)
    }
```

In my code, d and df contain the same values, because the results from the first loop are not concatenated. Comp is a list of 4

```
List of 4
 $ MP    : num [1:3] 94107 94110 94114
 $ Center: num [1:3] 94102 941103 941104
 $ 158   : num 94158
 $ Outer : num [1:4] 94112 94122 94132 94143
```

Df only contains the values for the last list "outer", but the loop should store the results for all four lists.
Does anyone know where the mistake is, I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (using `dput`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your below line(its iterate only once with value 4 ):

```
for (i in length(comp)){
```

that line should be:

```
for (i in 1:length(comp)){
```